# Is using periodic boundary conditions instead of fixed zero boundary conditions just for mathematical convenience?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, ideal-gas, boundary-conditions

In statistical physics, we get equivalent results for an ideal gas in a 3D box either if we fix the particle wavefunctions to be 0 on the box walls, or if we impose periodic boundary conditions so $\psi(0) = \psi(L)$ for a box of side-length L.

Similarly in condensed matter physics for a 1D harmonic chain it seems that the results for the normal modes would be equivalent if we force the normal mode solution to be 0 at the end points or if we imagine the chain is a closed circle and impose periodic boundary conditions.

My first question is why do this, it seems much more physically intuitive for a finite volume system to have fixed 0 boundary conditions than periodic - is it purely for mathematical convenience since complex exponentials are nicer to work with than trig functions?

My second question is that I understand that periodic boundary conditions are often good at modelling large/'infinite' systems, but how can that be in these cases where the *finite* volume solutions are equivalent to the periodic boundary conditions solutions?

Comment: This is not an example from statistical physics, but consider the vibration of something like a fan where the whole structure (blades and disk) is flexible. If there are $n$ identical blades which are all vibrating the same way, you only need to model one blade and a "pizza slice" of the disk. The boundaries between adjacent "slices" are periodic, but not fixed. For a typical jet engine turbine wheel, $n \approx 100$ so reducing the model size by a factor of $100$ is important in practice, not just "mathematical convenience."

Comment: My feeling is that the people use periodic condition when they are interested solely in the *bulk properties* of the system. Using the fixed boundary condition introduces the effect of open boundaries.